# Randomized Block Design

Tags: anova, experiment-design, degrees-of-freedom, randomness, blocking

It is desired to use a randomized block design with $4$ blocks of size $6$ each for testing the effects of $5$ treatments A,B,C,D and E. In each block, treatments B,C,D and E are replicated once each, while treatment A replicated twice to ensure more precise estimation and testing for A.
What will be the degree of freedom of treatments, blocks and error in this RBD model?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a self-study question, so I will limit myself to show how you can investigate yourself by simulating some data in R:

```r
    set.seed(7*11*13)# My public seed
    Blocks <- rep(1:4, each=6)
    T      <- rep(rep(LETTERS[1:5], c(2, rep(1, 4))), 4)
    library(tidyverse)
    mydata <- tibble(Blocks=as.factor(Blocks), T=as.factor(T), 
                     Y=rnorm(24, 10, 3))
    
    mod0 <- lm(Y  ~ Blocks + T, data=mydata)
    anova(mod0)
    Analysis of Variance Table
    
    Response: Y
              Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
    Blocks     3  12.142  4.0472  0.3098 0.8180
    T          4  61.268 15.3171  1.1726 0.3598
    Residuals 16 208.993 13.0621
```